# How do i read memory using pymem?

Tags: python

this code writes and reads memory from a program. the program is built in 64bit.
i have no problem using mem.write_float but when using mem.read, an error occurs

```
pymem.exception.MemoryReadError: Could not read memory at: 16, length: 8 - GetLastError: 29
```

does anyone have idea?

```
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import *


mem = Pymem("###.exe")
game_module = module_from_name(mem.process_handle, "###.exe").lpBaseOfDll


def getPtrAddr(address, offsets):
    addr = mem.read_longlong(address)
    for offset in offsets:
        if offset != offsets[-1]:
            addr = mem.read_longlong(addr + offset)
    addr = addr + offsets[-1]
    return addr

while True:

    mem.write_float(getPtrAddr(game_module + 0x06D26780, [0x28, 0x20, 0X08, 0x08, 0x170, 0x10, 0xE8]), 1000.233)
    
    mem.read_longlong(getPtrAddr(game_module + 0x06D26780, [0x28, 0x20, 0X08, 0x08, 0x170,0x10, 0xE8]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, read_longlong is reading integer. To jump from pointer to pointer you need to read pointer value. Instead of reading int, you can use "ptypes" see: https://pymem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-pymem.ptypes

You can use ptypes like this;

```
from pymem import Pymem
from pymem.ptypes import RemotePointer

pm = Pymem("###.exe")

def getPointerAddress(base, offsets):
    remote_pointer = RemotePointer(pm.process_handle, base)
    for offset in offsets:
        if offset != offsets[-1]:
            remote_pointer = RemotePointer(pm.process_handle, remote_pointer.value + offset)
        else:
            return remote_pointer.value + offset

pm.write_int(getPointerAddress(pm.base_address + 0x123ABC, offsets=[offset1, offset2, offset3]), 123456)
```

in your code;

```
game_module = module_from_name(mem.process_handle, "###.exe").lpBaseOfDll
```

and

```
pm.base_address
```

are basically the same thing